# How to export number of days from string "x days"

Tags: php, regex

How can I export the `4` from `string`:

> 9 buy property stocks over 4 days

I can export the numbers by doing:

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $string);
```

but I just want the number that is followed by `days`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a a matching regex with `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(?=\s*days)/', $string, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/prw0fi) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQYjte/1). The `\d+(?=\s*days)` pattern matches 1+ digits (`\d+`) that are followed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) and a substring `days`.

The same regex with a capturing group will look like

```
if (preg_match('/(\d+)\s*days/', $string, $m)) {
    echo $m[1];
}
```

See [another PHP demo](http://ideone.com/pRI1Iv) and [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IVg9Ci/1). Here, the 1+ digits are captured into a group and can be accessed via `$m[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$days = preg_replace('/.*(\d+) days/i', '\1', $string);
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/39OefZ/1)
[PHP Demo](https://ideone.com/LuUX34)